# onActivityResult gets called before onDestroy

Tags: android, android-activity

Inside MainActivity.java I make the following call:

```
Intent activity = new Intent(this, CameraDetectionActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(activity, request);
```

And at some point inside CameraDetectionActivity I run the following 2 lines (all happens in the GUI thread):

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

I would expect onDestroy to get called before onActivityResult in MainActivity but they are called in the opposite order.
Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

onDestroy is called at some point later, and that may be arbitrarily long.  We want to resume the next activity as quickly as possible so the UI is in there, and then take care of stopping and destroying previous activities only once the UI has switched.

Comment: Thanks. But than is there a way to find out/be noticed when a child activitay has been completely destroyed?

Comment: I did it by sending a broadcast intent in "onDestroy" of the inner activity, catched by the outer activity's broadcastreceiver. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Put attention pass your data to parent activity before calling `super.onDestroy();`

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```